# Open App for Specifc link in browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I want to open my Android app for a **specific** link not for the specific **host** so that whenever user types the url in browser my app should be shown in **Open With** options.

I have already got success in opening my app from browser link.

For e.g:

If user types: **www.abc.com** app must not be shown in **Open with** options. But if user types or clicks **www.abc.com/video** app must be shown.

I have tried diffrent combination of following but none of them works.

`<data android:pathPrefix="www.abc.com"
android:pathPattern=".*"
android:pathPrefix="/video/"                                android:scheme="http" />`

It shows me my app even if I have typed abc.com in web browser. But what i want is that my application should only be visible if the user typed exact url i.e. **www.abc.com/video**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i Understands after applying all the combinations of

`<data android:pathPrefix="www.abc.com" android:pathPattern=".*" android:pathPrefix="/video/" android:scheme="http" />`

is that:

1.) Browser throws intent for the url part before the /(slash) operator. For e.g:
If I write www.abc.com/terms, Browser will throw intent for www.abc.com. similary It will also check for www.abc.com/videos, www.abc.com/xyz, abc.com/, abc.com/videos and throws intent.

Now, Its our responsiblity to check other params in the incoming url and provide checks for the url we want to handle.

In my case, I have added check for second parameter videos if it contains, else show the home screen for the app.

Answer (score 0):

From Android docs:

> Each of these attributes is optional, but they are not independent of each other: For an authority to be meaningful, a scheme must also be specified. For a path to be meaningful, both a scheme and an authority must be specified.

Then you should use:

`android:scheme="http" android:host="www.abc.com" android:path="/video"`

Comment: Must include slash in path value. I edited my answer

Comment: It works because I tested it. But I read again your question and only now I understand what you want: user **types the url in browser** my app should be shown. That is not possible! Only works if you click a link.

Comment: No, that's not what I am asking..I am saying that if user types for e.g: "abc.com" in the url window My app should not be shown as   in options in Application Chooser Dialog. Instead if user types "abc.com/videos" only then my application must be visible in options under Application chooser Dialog.

Comment: What do you mean ***in the url window***? Is in browser?